# pandas: Why does the dtype of a column change on assignment to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame `bla` with a MultiIndex for columns:

```
ipdb> bla.dtypes
phases      end              datetime64[ns]
            name                     object
            start            datetime64[ns]
parameters  scanFrequency           float64
            tideFile                 object
```

Now I am performing some simple interpolation on a part of that frame and assign the result back to it:

```
bla['parameters'] = bla['parameters'].ffill()
```

Strangely, I end up with a data frame where the dtype of `scanFrequency` has changed:

```
ipdb> bla.dtypes
phases      end              datetime64[ns]
            name                     object
            start            datetime64[ns]
parameters  scanFrequency            object
            tideFile                 object
dtype: object
```

Why does this happen? The `ffill` doesn't change the type:

```
ipdb> bla['parameters'].ffill().dtypes
scanFrequency    float64
tideFile          object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a bug or expected behaviour, but the problem is that you are assigning multiple columns at once with mixed dtypes (object and float64) and because of this they are 'upcasted' to a common dtype, i.e. object dtype.

A workaround is to perform the `ffill` on separate columns. In your example, this would be:

```
bla[('parameters', 'scanFrequency')] = bla[('parameters', 'scanFrequency')].ffill()
```

This will preserve the original float64 dtype of the column.

Comment: Thanks. I have added an issues on github for the upcasting. The workaround works so far.

Comment: For future reference, the issue is here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/13433